# How do I get the backtrace for all the threads in GDB?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb, backtrace

Is there an equivalent command in GDB to that of WinDbg's `!process 0 7`?

I want to extract all the threads in a dump file along with their backtraces in GDB. `info threads` doesn't output the stack traces. So, is there a command that does?

Comment: The corresponding command for LLDB [is `bt all`](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) — in case someone found this via Google (who thinks GDB == LLDB).

Comment: With python the following works "
(gdb) python for thread in gdb.selected_inferior().threads(): thread.switch(); print(thread.num);gdb.execute('where')"

Comment: @kennytm this is good enough to be put in a question IMO

Comment: In fact, I created the exact question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67820406/how-do-i-get-the-backtrace-for-all-the-threads-in-lldb

Answer (score 405):

Generally, the backtrace is used to get the stack of the current thread, but if there is a necessity to get the stack trace of all the threads, use the following command.

```
thread apply all bt
```

Comment: To save the output to a file: `gdb <binary> <coredump> -ex "thread apply all bt" -ex "quit" > output.log`

Comment: You can shorten this to `t a a bt`

Comment: The command in @Doomsday comment hangs for me. Better try with `gdb <binary> <coredump> -ex "thread apply all bt" -ex "detach" -ex "quit" > output.log`, to avoid a question from gdb that blocks the command waiting for input.

Comment: The more generic syntax is `thread apply [threadno] [all] args`, where `[threadno]` can also be a space-separated list of thread identifiers (e.g. `2 3 4`), or a range (e.g. `2-6`).

Comment: @MarianoPaniga, or use `--batch`.

Answer (score 72):

> Is there a command that does?

```
thread apply all where
```

Comment: A synonym for `backtrace`.

Comment: Just tried, this is not a synonym for backtrace.

Comment: From `info gdb where`: *The names 'where' and 'info stack' (abbreviated 'info s') are
additional aliases for 'backtrace'.*

Answer (score 21):

When debugging with several threads, it is also useful to switch to a particular thread number and get the backtrace for that thread only.

From the GNU GDB threads [documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_24.html)

> For debugging purposes, GDB associates its own thread number--a small integer assigned in thread-creation order--with each thread in your program.

Usage:

```
info threads
```

Then identify the thread that you want to look at.

```
thread <thread_id>
```

Finally, use backtrace for just that thread:

```
bt
```

Answer (score -2):

If your process is running:

```
pstack $pid
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).