# C++11 is there a way to find out which thread has been forgotten to join

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have to debug and fix a **C++11** app in **Ubuntu 14.04** which - unfortunately - exits with a "***terminate called without an active exception***". Since there are myriads of threads started and stopped in different and changing orders - is there an easy way to figure out, which one causes the error message?
Thanks, Hermann

Comment: Can you attach a debugger, break on the last line of main, view the still active threads and their stack frames? I could do this on MS-Windows but I don't know enough about debugging on Ubuntu.

Comment: On Ubuntu, if you are running without an IDE, then GDB is your way to set breakpoints and display status. To use gdb, type "gdb <name of your program". If you pass arguments to your program, type "gdb --args <program> arg1 arg2...". One its starts, use the br command to set breakpoints, then type run. Read this post for details on debugging threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391808/getting-the-backtrace-for-all-the-threads-in-gdb

Comment: Richard Critten, @ScottK Thank you for your suggestion. I managed to inject GDB into the startup script (the 'app' actually consists of 6 cooperating apps) and in one of them GDB popped up with some helpful line numbers. So have something to dig into.