# How do I get the backtrace for all the threads in LLDB?

Tags: gdb, lldb

What's the LLDB equivalent of `thread apply all bt` in GDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding command for LLDB is simply `bt all`.

See https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#examining-thread-state

Comment: This answer was copied from this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391808/how-do-i-get-the-backtrace-for-all-the-threads-in-gdb#comment67798212_18391808.

I tested it and it works.