# Race condition in Morris's algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, memory-model

I implemented Morris's algorithm for a no-starve mutex from the [*Little Book of Semaphores*](https://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf) (page 85) almost verbatim. About half the time, it terminates correctly, and the other half it freezes up mid-execution. This indicates to me that there is some race condition, but I can't identify it.

I found other versions of Morris's algorithm pseudocode online, and they appear identical to what's in the *Little Book of Semaphores*. My current guess is that semaphores in C++ may work a little differently from semaphores in research and in other languages, but I'm not sure. What is causing this race condition?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <syncstream>

std::binary_semaphore t1(1);
std::binary_semaphore t2(0);
std::mutex mutex;
int room1 = 0;
int room2 = 0;

void Morris(std::stop_token stop_token){
    while (!stop_token.stop_requested()){
        mutex.lock();
            room1 += 1;
        mutex.unlock();
        
        t1.acquire();
            room2 += 1;
            mutex.lock();
            room1 -= 1;
            if (room1 == 0){
                mutex.unlock();
                t2.release();
            } else {
                mutex.unlock();
                t1.release();
            }

        t2.acquire();
            room2 -= 1;

            // critical region
            {
                std::osyncstream synced_out(std::cout);
                synced_out << "critical region of thread " << std::hex << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
            }
            // end critical region

            if (room2 == 0){
                t1.release();
            } else {
                t2.release();
            }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i){
        threads.emplace_back(Morris);
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    for (std::jthread& thread: threads){
        thread.request_stop();
    }
}
```

Commenter have indicated that they aren't experiencing freezing on Windows, so I'm including my computer information here:

```
compiler: g++12.3.0 -std=c++20 -lpthread -o
pc: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Intel Core i7-6700K, 4.00GHz x 8 (4 cores, 8 threads). processor is 64-bit x86
```

I am adding the backtrace of the last thread to print since it was asked for in the comments:

```
(gdb) thread 11
[Switching to thread 11 (Thread 0x7fffde7fc640 (LWP 115600))]
#0  syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38
38  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38
#1  0x0000555555558fd7 in std::__detail::__platform_wait<int> (__addr=0x5555555611a0 <t1>, __val=0) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/atomic_wait.h:108
#2  0x000055555555906c in std::__atomic_wait_address_bare<std::__atomic_semaphore::_M_acquire()::{lambda()#1}>(int const*, std::__atomic_semaphore::_M_acquire()::{lambda()#1}) (
    __addr=0x5555555611a0 <t1>, __pred=...) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/atomic_wait.h:444
#3  0x000055555555921c in std::__atomic_semaphore::_M_acquire (this=0x5555555611a0 <t1>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/semaphore_base.h:215
#4  std::counting_semaphore<1l>::acquire (this=0x5555555611a0 <t1>) at /usr/include/c++/12/semaphore:72
#5  0x0000555555557806 in Morris (stop_token=...) at /home/me/Desktop/nostarve/nostarve2.cpp:21
#6  0x000055555555be50 in std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(std::stop_token), std::stop_token> (__f=@0x555555574df0: 0x55555555779f <Morris(std::stop_token)>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/invoke.h:61
#7  0x000055555555bda1 in std::__invoke<void (*)(std::stop_token), std::stop_token> (__fn=@0x555555574df0: 0x55555555779f <Morris(std::stop_token)>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/invoke.h:96
#8  0x000055555555bd01 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::stop_token), std::stop_token> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul> (this=0x555555574de8) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_thread.h:279
#9  0x000055555555bcb6 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::stop_token), std::stop_token> >::operator() (this=0x555555574de8) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_thread.h:286
#10 0x000055555555bb8a in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::stop_token), std::stop_token> > >::_M_run (this=0x555555574de0)
    at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/std_thread.h:231
#11 0x00007ffff7cdc253 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#12 0x00007ffff7894ac3 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442
#13 0x00007ffff7926660 in clone3 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:81
```

Some things that I have tried that have not worked:

1. switching the `binary_semaphore`s out for `counting_semaphore`s
2. making `room1` and `room2` `std::atomic<int>`

Comment: And when you used your debugger to attach to the stuck process, where did your debugger show you all the execution threads were, and what did each one was waiting on?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not sure how to debug in the way you are describing. I'm used to using breakpoints with single-threaded code, and they aren't helping me at all here.

Comment: The behaviour that "it freezes" is typically  considered not a symptom of race condition but of deadlock. And all debuggers have possibility to just break right now, without setting any breakpoints.

Comment: Well, when I attach `gdb` to a multithread program, `i threads` lists all the threads, `bt #` shows me each threads backtrace, etc... For more information on using your debugger to debug multithreaded code, see your debugger's documentation. It is a very good idea to invest some time in learning how to use a debugger, so that in the future it's possible to figure out and fix all code issues by yourself.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I said race condition because it runs without freezing most of the time. The race condition is from modifying ```room1``` and ```room2```. Threads can't ```t1.acquire();``` unless ```room2 == 0```, and threads can't ```t2.acquire();``` unless ```room1 == 0```. My running theory is that it is freezing because there are unsynchronized writes to ```room1``` or ```room2```, and so one or the other isn't 0 at the expected time.

Comment: I could not reproduce the deadlock, the code works everytime on my machine. It would be good if you can show the backtrace. You don't even need to attach with gdb, simply execute the program with `gdb ./main` and hit `Ctrl+C` when you want to break. Look at the back trace like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67582487/7699037).

Comment: @MikevanDyke I added the backtrace to the OP. I'm not sure what I'm looking for. This looks way too complicated to be useful.

Comment: you'll need to examine the backtrace for all threads, are they all stuck in the same place? What are the values of `room1` and `room2`

Comment: I've run this as many times as I have patience for and I haven't seen it lock up.  But I tried it on Windows, in Visual Studio 2022 C++20.  The program has exited normally every time for me.  Perhaps you can give more details about your compiler version and system?

Comment: @Wyck g++, -std=c++20, -lpthread, -o, compiled on Ubuntu with 64-bit x86 processor

Comment: @Wyck Are you using `std::binary_semaphore`?  I don't see any semaphore specification for semaphore type mentioned in the description of Morris's algorithm in the linked document, and in general semaphores would be C++ *counting* semaphores.  I'm pretty sure exceeding a semaphore count limit invokes UB under C++20, so maybe your Windows `std::binary_semaphore` just happens to work as a `std::counting_semaphore` while OP's Linux `std::binary_semaphore` locks up?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've tried on Linux (via WSL) too and also couldn't reproduce the problem

Comment: @AndrewHenle I switched to counting semaphore and I'm still getting freezes.

Comment: @AlanBirtles g++12.3.0, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Intel Core i7-6700K, 4.00GHz x 8 (4 cores, 8 threads). And sorry, I'm not ignoring your question about ```room1``` and ```room2```, I'm still trying to figure how how to look at their values at the moment the program freezes.

Comment: @AlanBirtles At the moment the program freezes, ```room1``` = 49 and ```room2``` = 1. That seems pretty consistent across executions. The program freezes before the 5 second sleep ends, but by the time I pause, the main thread is executing ```std::jthread::join()```.

Comment: @AndrewHenle interesting hypothesis!  I ran OP code exactly as is, I just had to set `/std:c++20` to compile.  So I used whatever MSVC did as a result of that.  So I assume, yes, I was using `std::binary_semaphore` as written in the OP code.  The implementation by the compiler/runtime is something I'm not sure of based on your comment.  Seems worth investigating further though (which is why I asked about compiler versions originally).

Comment: Where are all the threads waiting?

Comment: @Wyck On a POSIX system, the C++ semaphore could be replaced with POSIX `sem_t` semaphores, and the GLIBC implementation on Linux systems does return an error if it overflows.  That would provide a way to at least check for any errors from acquiring or releasing the semaphores.

Comment: @Phil At this point the platform, system, and compiler version details seem relevant enough that they should be edited into the body of the question.

Comment: @AlanBirtles 49 threads are waiting on ```t1``` and one thread is waiting on ```t2```. It would make sense that ```room1``` or ```room2``` get off-by-one and it throws the whole program off.

Comment: @Phil I've compiled your original code using `g++` v13.1.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 and it ran quite a few times without problems on a 2-core/4-thread i5-3210M.  I installed `g++-13` after adding the Toolchain repo with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

Comment: @Phil That sure looks like the same problem.  And my successful results might be related to my lesser CPU.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have hit [GCC bug 104928](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104928), a race condition in the libstdc++ implementation of `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()`.  Congratulations, this is one of those rare occasions when it isn't [your fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/).  ;-)

I found that your test case is much easier to reproduce if you reduce the number of threads from 50 down to just 2.  I was able to actually step through the code in the deadlock case and observe the problem for myself, at which point I went searching for "semaphore" in the GCC Bugzilla and found it already reported.

---

To explain what goes wrong: in the function [`_S_do_spin`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fbfe43daec6443978df65530dc5f7f3f8a4e6f9e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_wait.h#L345) in `<bits/atomic_wait.h>`, we first load the current value of the semaphore's counter into `__val`.  If we are going to sleep, we will sleep (using `futex`) until the counter no longer equals this value.

Then we call `pred()` (a few times in a spin loop) to see if the desired predicate holds (i.e. if the semaphore value is nonzero) or if we should go to sleep.  `pred()` eventually calls [`_S_do_try_acquire`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fbfe43daec6443978df65530dc5f7f3f8a4e6f9e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/semaphore_base.h#L198C1-L198C71) in `<bits/semaphore_base.h>` which loads the counter **again**.

And now you see the problem.  The value of the counter may have changed in between, if another thread has acquired the semaphore.

So suppose thread A calls `acquire()` when the semaphore has a value of 1.  Then the first load sets `__val = 1`.  Suppose that, at this point, thread B acquires the semaphore.  Then when thread A calls `_S_do_try_acquire`, it observes the counter having value 0 and returns `false`.  So we are now going to invoke the futex wait system call with the value 1, i.e. saying to wait until `counter != 1`, which is the opposite of what we want.

If thread B still holds the semaphore at this point, then the futex wait will return immediately and no harm is done except for a wasted system call.  But suppose that thread B releases the semaphore first, setting the counter back to 1.  The semaphore should now be available for A to take, but instead the futex system call will wait indefinitely until its value is *no longer* 1, i.e. until some other thread acquires or releases the semaphore.  Of course, this may not ever happen.

---

Disappointingly, bug 104928 was reported back in March 2022 and appears to have received no attention at all.  I'll try to nudge it.